# How can I set a node name when using composing nodes with rclcpp?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm initializing nodes like so:

```
 rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exec;
 std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> laser_params = {rclcpp::Parameter("ip_address", "192.168.0.11")};
 rclcpp::NodeOptions laser_options;
 laser_options.parameter_overrides(laser_params);
 auto laser_node = std::make_shared<urg_node::UrgNode>(laser_options);
 exec.add_node(laser_node);
```

Which works fine, until I add a second node of the same type. I feel like I should be able to pass in a `name` argument to the node constructor, similar to [rclcpp::Node](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html). I noticed that many ros2-included nodes, like [laser_proc](https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_proc/blob/69a327b8b9fadd4fcb04a613448ef4a6bf408e24/src/laser_proc_component.cpp#L38) and [urg_node](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/6e2240b15c39d3fd2aa5daafe97039d9b563f5e8/src/urg_node.cpp#L47) have hardcoded node names. For now, I've modified `urg_node`'s constructor to have a name argument, which works, but I don't feel like I'm supposed to do this for all other nodes as well.

When using a launch.py file with `ComposableNodeContainer` and `ComposableNode`, I can pass a `name` argument to a node and be done with it.

How should I set a node name when running nodes in rclcpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369101/how-can-i-set-a-node-name-when-using-composing-nodes-with-rclcpp?/) by [Kurtoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/35713/kurtoid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurtoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/35713/kurtoid/) on 2021-01-07**:
I think I'm supposed to be remapping something, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you mentioned you can pass a name argument to the Launch: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Launch-system/

You can also pass a name argument on the command line: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Node-arguments/

If you're constructing the NodeOptions manually you can pass [arguments to the NodeOptoins](https://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1NodeOptions.html#ab0c61163fb466ceb980a001bdce2fb7a)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is for anyone else who wasted half a day trying to figure out how to create two instance of the same node with different names and topics.  The hints above and [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/349791/programmatically-load-parameters-from-yaml-file-in-rclcpp-node/) pointed me in the right direction.

I created two instances of the same node as follows:

```
  // Create the encoder nodes.
  rclcpp::NodeOptions options;
  options.arguments({"--ros-args", "-r", "__node:=encoder_left"});
  auto encoder_node_left = std::make_shared<EncoderNode>(options);
  options.arguments({"--ros-args", "-r", "__node:=encoder_right"});
  auto encoder_node_right = std::make_shared<EncoderNode>(options);
```

I then created matching topic names `encoder/left` and `encoder/right` with code in the `EncoderNode` constructor as follows:

```
   // Create the publisher using a mangled node name.
  std::string topic_name = get_name();
  // Replace _ with /
  size_t index = topic_name.find('_');
  topic_name[index] = '/';
  publisher_ = create_publisher<robot_msgs::msg::Encoders>(topic_name, 10);
```

---

Originally posted by [Andy Blight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50920/andy-blight/) with karma: 33 on 2022-11-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1